# what is the '-' (minus sign) for RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have that rule in the .htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ - [L,NC]
```

I don"t understand what is the "-" (the minus sign) for, just begin the [L,NC]

$ **-** [L,NC]

Answer (score 5):

From [the Apache mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> - (dash)
>     A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.

Effectively it means to take no action when that input URL pattern is matched. Following that with `[L]` makes sure no subsequent matches will be performed so the input URL is used "as-is".  This can be used to exempt one specific pattern from being rewritten when it would otherwise be matched by a more general pattern.

You won't see rules like the one in question too frequently, because it is usually possible to achieve the same result by reordering the `RewriteRule`, or by modifying the more general matching pattern so it doesn't match the exempt one to begin with.

Comment: is - and [L] redundant : is [L] enough ?

Comment: @yarek No, it isn't redundant because the format is `RewriteRule inputURL outputURL [flag,flag,flag]`. In this case, the `-` is used as a no-op in place of `ouputURL` so it is syntactically significant.

Comment: Instead of _"If input URL matches, rewrite to output URL, stop processing"_, it reads as _"If input URL matches, do not modify it, stop processing"_

Answer (score 1):

> A dash indicates that no substitution should be performed (the existing path is passed through untouched). This is used when a flag (see below) needs to be applied without changing the path.
>   (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

In combination with the `L` flag this indicates that these URLs should be processed without transformation and no other rules should be applied.